# Entity Framework - Configuring identifying key

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have some problems configuring EF mappings.

I have following classes (each dictionary can have 0, 1 or many `DictionaryDomain` objects):

```
public class Dictionary
{
  public virtual ICollection<DictionaryDomain> Domains { get; set; }
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DictionaryDomain
{
  public virtual Dictionary Dictionary { get; set; }
  public virtual int DictionaryId { get; set; } // I have added this after error described below
  public virtual Domain Domain { get; set; }
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Domain
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I removed domain (pseudocode)

```
Dictionary d = GetDictionary();
d.Domains.remove(some_object);
```

I got an error:

> A relationship from the 'DictionaryDomain_Dictionary' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'DictionaryDomain_Dictionary_Source' must also in the 'Deleted' state.

So I have added `DictionaryId` to the `DictionaryDomain` class as a part of key, and configured classes this way:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Dictionary>()
            .HasKey(e => e.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Dictionary>()
            .Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200);

        modelBuilder.Entity<DictionaryDomain>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.Dictionary);
            // Added from this line
        modelBuilder.Entity<DictionaryDomain>()
            .HasKey(e => new { e.Id, e.DictionaryId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<DictionaryDomain>()
            .Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<DictionaryDomain>()
            .Property(e => e.DictionaryId).HasColumnName("Dictionary_Id");
            // Till this line
        modelBuilder.Entity<DictionaryDomain>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.Domain);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Domain>()
            .HasKey(e => e.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Domain>()
            .Property(e => e.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200);
```

But after I have added the migration I got some strange migration:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.DictionaryDomains", new[] { "Domain_Id" });
        DropColumn("dbo.DictionaryDomains", "Id");
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.DictionaryDomains", name: "Domain_Id", newName: "Id");
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.DictionaryDomains");
        AlterColumn("dbo.DictionaryDomains", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.DictionaryDomains", new[] { "Id", "Dictionary_Id" });
        CreateIndex("dbo.DictionaryDomains", "Id");
    }
```

This was not what I expected (I expected only recreation of primary key).

I have no idea what have I done wrong. Maybe I don't have enough understanding how EF works, but any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add `DomainId` to class `DictionaryDomain`, and to add this field to composite key.

Class looks like this:

```
public class DictionaryDomain
{
    public virtual Dictionary Dictionary { get; set; }
    public virtual int DictionaryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Domain Domain { get; set; }
    public virtual int DomainId { get; set; }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and mapping:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<DictionaryDomain>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.Dictionary);
        modelBuilder.Entity<DictionaryDomain>()
            .HasKey(e => new {e.Id, e.DictionaryId, e.DomainId});
        modelBuilder.Entity<DictionaryDomain>()
            .Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<DictionaryDomain>()
            .Property(e => e.DictionaryId).HasColumnName("Dictionary_Id");
        modelBuilder.Entity<DictionaryDomain>()
            .Property(e => e.DomainId).HasColumnName("Domain_Id");
        modelBuilder.Entity<DictionaryDomain>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.Domain);
```

after that I got correct migration:

```
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.DictionaryDomains");
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.DictionaryDomains", new[] { "Id", "Dictionary_Id", "Domain_Id" });
```

After that removing from collection works as expected - for now :)